# Как сравнить все списки по конкретному элементу?

Tags: python

Дан список списков:

`[["a", "b", "c", 1], ["a", "b", "c", 2], ["a", "b", "c", 3]]`

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно сравнить все списки между собой по последнему элементу и вывести список с большим значением.

В итоге должен получится этот список: `["a", "b", "c", 3]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Использование [max](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) легко решит эту задачу:

```
items = [["a", "b", "c", 1], ["a", "b", "c", 2], ["a", "b", "c", 3]]
print(
    max(items, key=lambda x: x[-1])
)
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 3]
```

Параметр `key` нужен для определения критерия работы функции. Параметр принимает функцию, в которую будут помещаться элементы.

Это `key=lambda x: x[-1]` даст возможность находить максимум по последнему элементу под списков